# Custom success handler doesn't have any effect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

i'm trying to make a custom success handler for my application. But when successfully authenticated only the token is returned and the correct page is not displayed.

here is the successhandler:

```
 private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();


    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException {

        handle(request, response, authentication);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }

    protected void handle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication
    ) throws IOException {

        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            log.debug(
                    "Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to "
                            + targetUrl);
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(final Authentication authentication) {

        Map<String, String> roleTargetUrlMap = new HashMap<>();
        roleTargetUrlMap.put("Student", "templates/Student-AllocatedEquipmentHistory.html");
        roleTargetUrlMap.put("Researcher", "templates/Researcher-AllocatedEquipmentHistory.html");

        final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (final GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            String authorityName = grantedAuthority.getAuthority();
            if(roleTargetUrlMap.containsKey(authorityName)) {
                return roleTargetUrlMap.get(authorityName);
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

i used an example posted on [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-after-login)`.
```

and this is the filterchain:

```
  @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws  Exception{

    httpSecurity
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
           .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("Implementation/user/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/LoginPage").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("resources/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("static/css/**", "static/js/**", "static/css/images/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
            .loginPage("/LanderPage")
            .failureUrl("/Login?error=true")
            .permitAll();


    return httpSecurity.build();

}
```

and this is the authentificationService:

```
`public String authenticate( User user){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        var userDetails= customUserDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
        String token  = tokenGenerator.generateToken(userDetails);
        return token;
    }`
```

i believe the handler is not being executed at all becaue i tried a few prints and it did not return anything. i also tried changing the handler all together and that also didn't work. so i believe spring is not executing it. i removed the customFilter to see if it is blocking the handler but nothing changed so it's blocked by something else.